# Symfony entities deleted when linked entity is created

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I have a problem creating an entity `Annonce`. In an `Annonce`, I have a `Categorie`.

The creation of an `Annonce` used to work, but now, it does not work anymore (I don't know why).

When I submit the creation form, all the categories are deleted (I see it in the doctrine profiler) and then it tries to save the annonce but the category I have selected in the form does not exists anymore as it has been deleted just before.

I don't know why there is those deletions.
Here is my code :

AnnonceController newAction :

```
/**

 * Creates a new annonce entity.

 *

 * @Route("/nouvelle", name="ad_new")

 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})

 */

public function newAction(Request $request)

{

    $annonce = new Annonce();



    if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {

        $annonce->setUser($this->getUser());

    }



    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repoCategorie = $em->getRepository('AnnoncesBundle:Categorie');

    $rootCategories = $repoCategorie->findRootCategories();



    foreach ($rootCategories as $rootCategory)

    {

        $rootCategory->setEnfants($repoCategorie->findByParent($rootCategory));

    }



    $form = $this->createForm('AnnoncesBundle\Form\AnnonceType', $annonce);

    $form->handleRequest($request);





    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {



        $annonce->setComplexId(uniqid('', true));

        $annonce->setDateCreation(new \DateTime("now"));

        $annonce->setDateModification(new \DateTime("now"));



        $em->persist($annonce);

        $em->flush();



        // On traite les image

        $this->gerePhotos($annonce);





        $stat = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Stats")->find(1);

        $stat->setNbAnnonces($stat->getNbAnnonces() + 1);



        $em->flush();



        $urlHelper = $this->container->get('AppBundle\Services\UrlHelper');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('ad_confirme', array('id' => $annonce->getId(), 'complexId' => $annonce->getComplexId()));

    }



    return $this->render('annonce/new.html.twig', array(

        'annonce' => $annonce,

        'form' => $form->createView(),

        'categories' => $rootCategories

    ));

}
```

`Categorie` is defined in the `Annonce` entity like that :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AnnoncesBundle\Entity\Categorie")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categorie_code", referencedColumnName="code")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Merci de renseigner la catégorie")
*/
private $categorie;
```

The `Categorie` entity code:

```
<?php

namespace AnnoncesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Categorie
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="categorie")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AnnoncesBundle\Repository\CategorieRepository")
 */
class Categorie
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position_affichage", type="integer")
     */
    private $positionAffichage;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $code;


    /**
     * Many Categories have One Category.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AnnoncesBundle\Entity\Categorie", inversedBy="enfants")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_code", referencedColumnName="code", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * One Category has Many children Categories.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AnnoncesBundle\Entity\Categorie", mappedBy="parent",orphanRemoval=true,  cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $enfants;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->enfants = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $code
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPositionAffichage()
    {
        return $this->positionAffichage;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $positionAffichage
     */
    public function setPositionAffichage($positionAffichage)
    {
        $this->positionAffichage = $positionAffichage;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     *
     * @return Categorie
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom complet
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNomComplet()
    {
        if ($this->parent)
        {
            return $this->parent->getNom() . " > " . $this-> nom;
        }
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param Categorie $parent
     *
     * @return Categorie
     */
    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return Categorie
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEnfants()
    {
        return $this->enfants;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $enfants
     */
    public function setEnfants($enfants)
    {
        $this->enfants = $enfants;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return "".$this->code;
    }

}
```

And the  Doctrine profiler logs :

```
17  0.28 ms     

"START TRANSACTION"

Parameters:

[]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
18  11.37 ms    

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "enfants"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
19  115.71 ms   

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "services"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
20  0.54 ms     

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "jardin"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
21  0.61 ms     

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "art"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
22  0.96 ms     

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "loisirs"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
23  0.62 ms     

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "maison"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
24  0.36 ms     

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "vehicules"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
25  0.34 ms     

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "immobilier"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
26  0.33 ms     

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "emploi"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
27  0.28 ms     

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "electronique"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
28  0.27 ms     

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "animaux"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
29  0.19 ms     

DELETE FROM categorie WHERE parent_code = ?

Parameters:

[▼
  "divers"
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
30  100.67 ms   

INSERT INTO annonce (complex_id, titre, prix, monnaie, monnaie_paiement, type, texte, troc, photos, show_tel, date_creation, date_modif, date_renvoi_mail_confirmation_creation, confirme, validee, refusee, paiement_effectue, pack_urgent, pack_photo, pack_remontee, frequence_remontee, jour_remontee, nb_remontees_restantes, date_alaune, date_derniere_mise_alaune, date_fin_alaune, taille, taille_enfant, marque, modele, date_mise_circulation, energie_vehicule, boite_vitesse, kilometrage, type_bien, surface, nb_pieces, classe_energie, ges, meuble, capacite_personnes, type_contrat, remuneration, experience, temps_plein, handi_acces, duree, categorie_code, user_id, anonymousUser_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Parameters:

[▼
  1 => "5b4864d0efb892.92513412"
  2 => "tesq"
  3 => null
  4 => "euro"
  5 => "euro"
  6 => "offre"
  7 => "desc"
  8 => 0
  9 => null
  10 => 0
  11 => "2018-07-13 10:37:36"
  12 => "2018-07-13 10:37:36"
  13 => null
  14 => 0
  15 => 0
  16 => 0
  17 => 0
  18 => 0
  19 => 0
  20 => 0
  21 => null
  22 => null
  23 => null
  24 => null
  25 => null
  26 => null
  27 => null
  28 => null
  29 => null
  30 => null
  31 => null
  32 => null
  33 => null
  34 => null
  35 => null
  36 => null
  37 => null
  38 => null
  39 => null
  40 => null
  41 => null
  42 => null
  43 => null
  44 => null
  45 => 0
  46 => 0
  47 => null
  48 => "enfants_livres"
  49 => 11
  50 => null
]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
31  43.06 ms    

"ROLLBACK"

Parameters:

[]

View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
```

Anyone has a clue to give me to understand why these `Categorie` entities are deleted ?

Thanks !

Comment: I guess that your orphanRemoval directive in your enfants field is maybe responsible for the deletion ... what happens if you remove it?

Comment: why are you doing this `$rootCategory->setEnfants($repoCategorie->findByParent($rootCategory));` at each call??

Comment: @JimPanse I have removed the orphanRemoval and I don't have the error anymore ! Thanks !!
**Constantin** : It is to create the tree structure of the categories that will be used to generate the selector widget

Comment: Even if the error is gone: Please don't remove things if you are not aware of its purpose

Comment: I understand what `orphanRemoval`makes. I don't have the option of modifying/removing or adding Categories so this kind of option isn't useful.

Comment: Actually it is really weird the line I pointed. It feels to me that you are doing this for nothing.

`$repoCategorie->findByParent($rootCategory)` 

this should give you categories with parent set to rootCategory from the database.

and then you set the childrens `$rootCategory->setEnfants()` 
the categories you got before but these should be the same.

Feels to me that $rootCategory-> getEnfants() give you the same thing than $repoCategorie->findByParent($rootCategory)

Comment: @Constantin `$repoCategorie->findByParent($root)` return all the children for this parent. So, I set `$root->setEnfants()` with this result to build the categorie tree.

Comment: So to make it clearer. 
Let's say you have a root category A and childrens A1, A2, A3 (so all parent fields should be A).

With your query to the DB you take every categories witch the parent is A, these are the 3 childrens A1, A2, A3.

And these 3 categories you set them as children of the root category, which is stupid because they already are children. 

And because you replace the array of childrens, the orphan removal removes your categories from DB... 

Am I wrong?

Comment: @Constantin I `setChildren` because when I get rootCategories, they don't come with `enfants` filled. So I need to fill this value for each rootCategories. That is why I loop over rootCategories and setChildren for each of them. I need a `$rootCategories` variable containing all the tree of categories

Comment: This is where you are wrong. rootCategories comes with children filled, and if they don't (I don't know your setup), you just have to join them in your repo, so that they come.
But I am pretty sure that if you try to dump the children of the first root category, you will see that they come from the db, this is how symfony + doctrine works...
Then just try this you will see `dump($rootCategories[0]->getEnfants()); die();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174944/discussion-between-constantin-and-wyllyjon).